# Can sshguard filter TCP+UPD ports? If so, how to prevent that?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall, ufw

I understand that `sshguard` guards from Brute Force Attacks on SSH, but does it also serve a `iptables` manager to filter TCP+UPD ports?

I could indeed use [ufw](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) to filter all ports, then unfilter the ones I desire, this way:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp 9000/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/upd 
sudo ufw status verbose
```

And yet I'm afraid to install `sshbuard` and then maybe have some kind of conflict with `ufw`.

I would desire to make sure `sshguard` doesn't filter or unfilter any ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sshguard` will not be filtering or unfiltering any of your ports.
It is reading log files, creates an iptables chain and "manage the rules" like adding/restricting ip addresses bruteforcing/exceeding connections limit on ports configured in `sshguard`.

**So NO there won't be any conflict between `sshguard` and `ufw`.**